# Жизненный цикл данных в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

В файле базы данных находятся стоп-слова, которые надо вывести на экран оператора, работающего в WPF приложении. Насколько я понял из соседних ответов на тему WPF, каждое стоп-слово надо поместить в объект данных, в дальнейшем этот объект будет через байндинг передан в контрол WPF и появится на экране.
Пытаюсь понять что происходит на каждом шаге, скажем так, жизни данных.
Дальше я перечислю, что удалось собрать, если есть ошибки или недостающие шаги, то исправьте.

1. Набор байт из базы данных считываются и передается в WPF приложение.
2. Набор байт преобразуется в текст.
3. Создается объект данных и в него копируется текст, полученный в п.2
4. Через байндинг контрола WPF происходит запрос текста у объекта данных. Непонятно, текст остается типом String или преобразуется в Object?
5. Байндинг передает полученное в контрол WPF, где формируется изображение и выводит на экран.
6. Объект данных и сам текст по идее уже не нужны и занимаемая память может быть осовобождена.

Хотелось бы понять почему в WPF сделано так, а не иначе? На мой взгляд выглядит несколько избыточным.

Comment: Избыточным такое выглядит только если у вас простое приложение. Например, если вы пользуетесь binding'ом чтобы один раз передать одно значение, то он может быть и не так уж и нужен. Но если значение у вас в модели или в UI может изменяться, и вам нужно автоматически переносить эти изменения, тут уже без Binding'а не обойтись. И это только простейший сценарий.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что без байндинга невозможно обойтись в WPF? Но как я понял из документации в WPF используются события. Насколько я знаю, в байндинге используется механизм событий, который является базовым для .NET, а это значит что байндинг можно не использовать.

Comment: Ну, их можно не использовать, да. Но тогда всё это вам придётся делать вручную. Этим обычно никто не занимается, но если очень хочется, то можно.

Answer (score 3):

Всё довольно просто - WPF говорит вам, что отображение данных не должно влиять на код, просто пишите код, преобразуйте данные, а отображение будет работать само. Т.е. не надо думать о том, как будет отображена строка - будет это текстбокс, текстблок, лейбл, батон, что угодно - достаточно создать строку. Конечно, кроме примитивных типов есть и более сложные кейсы, но и тут WPF говорит - не надо завязываться на контролы, пишите классы, поддерживающие пару интерфейсов - накидать на такой класс вьюшку будет дешево и просто, без изменения кода.

Стоит отметить, что WPF - это в основном Enterprise сектор, т.е. здоровые и долгоживущие приложения. Стоимость изменений в них должна быть минимальна и вероятность внести баги просто изменением цвета\рамочки\растояния вообще равна нулю. Поэтому WPF довольно принципиально отличается от WinForm - никаких статичных размеров контролов, никаких привязок к цифрам - все адаптивное, куча заморочек типа стилей\триггеров, чтобы поведение не надо было программировать вручную.

Конечно, тут есть и свои минусы. Когда приложение на пару тысяч строк кода, найти причину визуального бага становится достаточно сложно, ибо есть порядка 10 разных источников данных для любого свойства WPF контрола. Поэтому появляются различные фреймворки, с одной стороны упрощающие создание однообразных вьюшек, с другой - неявно накладывающих ограничения на использование плюшек WPF, чтобы не создавать ад.

А теперь по тому что вы описали. dotNet использует ссылки для классов, а значит в простейшем случае класс, считанный с базы, содержит N полей примитивных типов. В итоге, класс либо напрямую, либо через обертку уходит в контролы WPF, занимая ровно столько же памяти, ибо где надо просто ставится ссылка на экземпляр, а не создается новый. В случае со строкой, она либо отображается напрямую, т.е. экземпляр вообще один, либо создается один дубль на уровне вьюмодели в каком нибудь MVVM - который отвечает за отображение\изменение данных.

Стоит заметить, что строковые данные - дешевые. Если вы конечно не пытаетесь отобразить "Войну и Мир". Если лезть внутрь WPF, то избыточным скорее будет отображение, ибо на каждый чих пользователя расчетов мб довольно много. Если у вас нет прямо сейчас проблем с отображением (лагающая анимация, пропадание контролов, мигание) и с памятью (OutOfMemory, забивание свопа) - проще об этом не задумываться. А когда появятся - всяко придётся брать в руки профайлер и искать причину утечки, а не раздумывать, не потерял ли я на биндингах пару лишних байт.